# Nginx reverse proxy for Apache: does Apache need SSL certificates?

Tags: apache2, proxy, nginx, ssl, certificates

I'm setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache2, in order to run a  webmail service and a WordPress site in a secure environment.

Does Apache need to know about the SSL certificates, or is it enough for Nginx to know about them?

I understand that I need to set up an Nginx server to forward any requests for PHP scripts to the Apache2 server listening on a different port. I have set up Nginx to redirect all HTTP traffic to port 443. Here's an extract from the Nginx server block:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Does this mean that Apache2 only needs to listen for HTTP traffic? If so, how do I set up Apache2 so that it doesn't provoke an error if no SSL certificates are assigned?

Comment: No , you use the ssl (https) on nginx and pass the requests to apache over http (at least that is what I would do). nginx will then pass the data (*.php) back to the client over ssl (https).

Comment: @Panther So I can simply delete the default file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf to disable the HTTPS service via Apache? Or is there a more elegant way to tell Apache not to ask for a certificate?

Comment: Yes, just run Apache via http, no need for https when you are using nginx as a proxy.